# Image does not appear on div even though div class changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show an animation on .gif format, before the page loads JSON data on the div. But It does not show gif.

I check in the console if it does not change the class, but it changes.

Basically code should work like this:

1- Press Button

2- Load image (css class: "loading")

3- Start json call (It takes around 8 secs)

4- Load table  (css class: "loaded")

- HTML and javascript are in seperate files
- gif animation loads when I change the classes into the opposite. But this time it loads on the json table data.

CSS:

```
div.loading {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #FFF url('loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

div.loaded {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function loadOutputs() {
console.log(document.getElementById('loadingElement').className);
document.getElementById("loadingElement").className = "loading";
console.log(document.getElementById('loadingElement').className);

makeProxyCall(
        "http://localhost:9090/myService/tool/runTool?tool=myTool",
        function(data) {


            var globalCounter = 0;
            var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

            var trheader = "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Value</td><td>Type</td><td>UnitOfMeasure</td><td>Mode</td></tr>"
            tbody.innerHTML = trheader;

            for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var tr = "<tr>";
                //if (obj[i].value.toString().substring(obj[i].value.toString().indexOf('.'), obj[i].value.toString().length) < 2) obj[i].value += "0";

                tr += "<td>" + data[0][i].name + "</td>" + "<td>"
                        + data[0][i].value + "</td>" + "<td>"
                        + data[0][i].type + "</td>" + "<td>"
                        + data[0][i].unitOfMeasure + "</td>" + "<td>"
                        + data[0][i].mode + "</td></tr>";
                tbody.innerHTML += tr;
            }
        });
document.getElementById("loadingElement").className = "loaded";
console.log(document.getElementById('loadingElement').className);
```

}

HTML:

```
<div id="loadingElement" class="loaded">
    <button type="button" class="btn-blue"
        style="top: 80px; right: 130px;" onclick="loadOutputs()">Load
            Outputs</button>
            <table>
                <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is executed asynchronously. The classname 'loaded' is set before `makeproxycall` is finished.

Add the classname switch to the end of the callback function in `makeproxycall`:

```
makeProxyCall(
  "http://localhost:9090/myService/tool/runTool?tool=myTool",
  function(data) {


    var globalCounter = 0;
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

    var trheader = "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Value</td><td>Type</td><td>UnitOfMeasure</td><td>Mode</td></tr>"
    tbody.innerHTML = trheader;

    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var tr = "<tr>";
      //if (obj[i].value.toString().substring(obj[i].value.toString().indexOf('.'), obj[i].value.toString().length) < 2) obj[i].value += "0";

      tr += "<td>" + data[0][i].name + "</td>" + "<td>"
                   + data[0][i].value + "</td>" + "<td>"
                   + data[0][i].type + "</td>" + "<td>"
                   + data[0][i].unitOfMeasure + "</td>" + "<td>"
                   + data[0][i].mode + "</td></tr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
    }
    document.getElementById("loadingElement").className = "loaded";
  });
```